# Perl regex: search of all class="" in string and save values in array

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get classes from a string in HTML document.
String for example:

```
<span class="bullet first">Some</span>Published <abbr class="published">Sometexthere</abbr></p>
```

So, what I am trying to acheive is to get all "classes" in the string (bullet, first, published).
But the problem is that it can be any amount of class="" in the string.
So, I guess there is no way to do that with one regex, I need cycle here?

Comment: You probably don't want to use a regex, but you want to parse HTML and use the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding this to answer the part ***'So, I guess there is no way to do that with one regex, I need cycle here?'***

You have to use the modifier g in the regexp

```
my $text = '<span class="bullet first">Some</span>Published <abbr class="published">Sometexthere</abbr></p>';
while($text =~ /class\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/g) {
  print "class --> $1\n";
}
```

This is the result

```
class --> bullet first
class --> published
```

Answer (score 2):

No matter how you do it, it's a two step process:

1. Extract the values of the class attributes ("bullet first", "published").
2. Extract the classes from those values ("bullet", "first", "published").

XML::LibXML (which is also an HTML parser):

```
my @classes =
   map split(' ', $_->getValue()),          # Step 2
      $xpc->findnodes('*/@class', $node);   # Step 1
```

(Or maybe `.//*/@class`, depending on what you want.)

Comment: Thank you for showing XML::LibXML. It's very helpfull! Will make my life easier now and in future.

Comment: `$xpc` is an XML::LibXML::XPathContext object, cause I presume you'd be needing one to define HTML's namespace

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the html does not contain complex data such as `<p> class="abc" <\p>` then looping throug a regex with the global modifier will cause it to start it the place it matched the last time.
Example

```
While ($_=~ /class="(.*?)"/g) {
    #process class names here
    #class is in $1
}
```

However for general use a html parser is recomended as this will process the string `<p> class="abc" <\p>` as containing the class abc